# Regex for matching branch jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I have a requirement to allow patch branch too with master branch (we use git).

```
stages {
    stage('PR Build') {
        when {
            beforeAgent true
            expression {
                        isMaster = env.BRANCH_NAME == masterBranchName
                        isPatch = env.BRANCH_NAME !=~ /Patch_For_*([a-z0-9]*)/
                        echo "isMaster : ${isMaster} , isPatch : ${isPatch}"
                        return !isMaster && !isPatch
                       }
        }
        steps {
            script{
                buildType = 'PR'
            }
            // Do PR build here...
        }
    }

    stage('Build master / patch branch') {
        when {
            beforeAgent true
            expression {
                        isMaster = env.BRANCH_NAME == masterBranchName
                        isPatch = env.BRANCH_NAME !=~ /Patch_For_*([a-z0-9]*)/
                        echo "isMaster : ${isMaster} , isPatch : ${isPatch}"
                        return isMaster || isPatch
                       }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                buildType = 'deployment'
                )
            }
            // Do master or patch branch build and deployment
        }
    }
```

Here the issue is in regex part of Patch branch. I want jenkins to check whether the patch branch is starting with `Patch_For_shortCommitIDSha` for example `Patch_For_87eff88`

But the regex I wrote wrongly allows branches other than branches starting with `Patch_For_`

Comment: `=~` means to match. `!~` means to not match. I am unsure what behavior results from `!=~`, but it probably is not what you want.

Comment: I got the answer. It was a mistake in my logic. I will update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
isPatch = (env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /Patch_For_*([a-z0-9]*)/)
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is with NOT operator.

'!=~' is not valid match operator for Groovy, and must be replaced. Rewritten form of IF NOT MATCH regex, should look like this:

`isPatch = !(env.BRANCH_NAME =~ /Patch_For_*([a-z0-9]*)/)`

So you see, NOT operator **!** should go out of boolean match expression, which should be enclosed to parentheses and NOT put right before it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check and reply / make it as correct answer once confirmed (I got my problem fixed already).

Comment: This answer doesn't work. I see - 
{ steps { script { if !(params.Branch =~ /feature/ ) { ...} else {..} } }
                                 ^
1 error